# What is the name of the song at the start of K: Return of Kings?

Tags: music, k-project

Does anyone know the song title in **K: Return of Kings** episode 1, at the first scene where Scepter 4 and HOMRA meet on the rooftop of a building, from 00:06 to 03:20?

I tried to google it but the result was only the opening and the ending of K.

Comment: I would suggest waiting for the release of the Original Soundtrack (OST), pretty hard to know otherwise.

Comment: Yeah I will wait then, I was a bit hasty. Sorry for slow comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official audio is not yet released but someone made a piano cover in youtube. Here's the link:

https://youtu.be/cu7qN-_80w0

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the name is Prelude by Mikio Endo